# Identify me - (An easy riddle)

Tags: knowledge

I am a **South Korean** car model named after a **United States** city which in turn is named in **Spanish**. Identify me.

It is a quick and easy riddle. I am sharing it just for fun.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be trivia rather than a puzzle.

Comment: Is a trivia not allowed in this forum? Isn't it just another form of a puzzle?

Comment: This is a question/answer site (not really a forum) specifically for puzzles. Trivia is purely knowledge based and doesn't really have the "aha" moment that puzzles have.

Comment: I am disinclined to acquiesce to your point above. Any puzzle requires some basic knowledge - frequently some basic Math or Science. This trivia  is no exception. It just requires some basic general knowledge.

Comment: @VHS: There's a difference between requiring knowledge and requiring *only* knowledge. This does not have any "aha" moment - it's just pure trivia, not a puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could also be the

> [Hyundai Santa Fe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyundai_Santa_Fe)
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> [Hyundai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyundai_Motor_Company) is a south korean manufacturer, [Santa Fe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Fe,_New_Mexico) is the capital of New Mexico, and *"Santa Fe"* is Spanish and means *"holy faith"* in English.

Comment: Santa Fe is a *state* in New Mexico?

Comment: @Areeb Wow, I got "a bit" confused there, lol.

Comment: no biggie, states and cities are *practically* the same thing

Answer (score 3):

You are the

> Hyundai Tucson (named after Tucson, Arizona)

Comment: frankly speaking, I didn't even know that this is also a possible answer. Good one.